# Ask "So, what's the job?"... in a more refined way

Tags: job-search, job-description, correspondence

I've come across several job descriptions in vacancy advertisements relevant to my field that are vague and unclear to say the least. What's a good approach to ask what exactly the job is before going through the interview process?

Comment: Please clarify: Is that some highly specific field where managers seek candidates directly or is it some field where a recruiter is outsourced to sieve through thousands of CVs before recommending a handful to the manager?

Comment: What is so "unrefined" about *“So, what's the job?”*

Comment: @AIBreveleri While I can't speak for Riku, as an interviewer I would immediately question why the applicant had applied if they didn't know what the job was.

Answer (score 49):

Here's a no fuss straight forward approach:

> Hello,
>
> I saw the role regarding **[job title]**, and am interested as it's in my
>   area of expertise. I find that the duties of this role differ between
>   companies, so can you give me more details on its scope?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Riku

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I'll ask in a comment instead of just changing it: Shouldn't it be "differ" instead of "differs", since "duties" is plural?

Comment: @Heinzi IMO "differ" is correct as it refers to the role and not the duties. If you would ask about multiple roles then "differ" would be correct. "...duties of these roles differ between companies..."

Comment: @Heinzi correct - duties is the subject of the verb, so it should be differ

Comment: You can also ask, "what does it take to succeed in this job?"

Comment: IMHO, should be "can differ", rather than differs or differ.

Comment: "... duties ... can vary ... "?

Answer (score 7):

**Most of the times, the best approach is just being straightforward.**

Follow whichever is applicable in the below order:

- If you have a contact number provided in the job listing, call them up and ask about the job description.
- If you have don't have a contact number, but a point-of-contact email ID, drop an email showing your interest and asking about the clarification for the role.
- If you don't have any specific contact information, find out the corresponding company communication channel (generic ID, phone number), and ask them to get you in touch with the people responsible for recruitment to talk about the job post.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are good for the literal question, but I'll take a different perspective and posit that a job description being so vague that you can't even confidently *start* the interview process is such a red flag that you should probably just skip over such jobs entirely.

Usually, it means the truthful answer to `So, what's the job?` is `We don't really know`. Outside of a few particular situations such as the job being exploratory in nature, or at an early stage startup, this is probably not a good thing.

But even in the case your eventual manager *does* have a clear idea of what they need, the fact the job description ended up being vague anyway suggests they don't have much control over their own recruitment pipeline. Why? What other aspects of work might be similar? On the surface, this doesn't reflect well on the culture at this organisation.

Comment: Not entirely ... as to my experience many companies have difficulties specifying job descriptions especially regarding jobs that don't touch their primary field of operation. Most common examples are the various IT jobs for about any production or commerce oriented organization. They know its necessary but don't have a real clue what's it about. So in many cases they ask a friend or a real consultant.The asked person sets up the job-ad and lists things he deems necessary and welcome to the mess of vague / non-saying job descriptions.

Comment: Often it's just an agency fishing for CVs, it's vague because there is no actual job just yet, but they expect something similar soon.

Comment: @RobinBennett yes good point - that's a common explanation for this also. Kind of in the same bracket as 'we don't really know' - takeaway being if the job description isn't very precise and targeted, it's reasonably likely applying will be a waste of your time.

Comment: @eagle275 sure, I agree, I think pretty much everything you said falls under what I meant by their answer being 'we don't really know'

Comment: OK .. but usually they DO know what the hired person is asked to do - they only fail at putting it together in context. Example " We want a graduated (IT) student to continue developing our applications, maintain the database, create office macros and various other stuff" - granted anybody with a university degree in IT studied it to not "DO" those tasks but to lead the actual "bees" doing those tedious tasks.

Comment: Rejecting the employer, or even assuming the culture is bad, because of a vague job description seems like a great way to miss opportunities in order to save the 5 minutes of time a phone call that could clarify the whole situation would take. Strikes me as a poor trade-off. There are all kinds of legitimate reasons why a good team might have poorly worded job descriptions.

Comment: @dwizum you're right of course, there will be loads of possible exceptions to this. I'd suggest on average, though, it'd be a red flag. It's highly contextual. If it's a short list, and it really takes only 5 mins to call up and ask, obviously you should probably do that. If however you are doing a first pass through 10s or 100s of job descriptions, and it's quite possible it'd take more than 5 mins per job to find the right contact details, get through to the right person etc, then it's probably a better strategy to just disregard the vague ones

Comment: @dwizum I have seen this happen on government contracting job postings (USA). The post will have every coding language in use for the last 50 years, even though they are really only looking for a C# developer. It's best to call and ask, and even ask if the person you would be working for could be part of the interview so you can get a clear answer